# RecyclerView pushes its below button out of the screen in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am attempting to set up a layout with an "X" button pinned to the top of the screen, and then two elements centered in the view. One a recycler view and then, pinned below the recycler view, a button for form submission. The layout I currently have worked until the recycler view outgrows its bounds. Then the submission button is pushed below the bounds of the view and the recycler view does not stay within the layout. How can I center the two recycler and button views but not have the button go past view bounds if the recycler view grows large?

**View With Small Recycler View Appears As (it should be centered. my example is slightly off.)**

[image]

**How View Should Appear with Larger Recycler View (the recycler view's content is too large to fit so it scrolls)**

[image]

**How View Actually Appears with Larger Recycler View (the recycler view does scroll, but now it pushes the button off the bottom of the view, which appears as the button being cut off)**

[image]

**Relevant Code Block for XML Layout**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.45"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/backgroundLightSecondary"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_close"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
            android:textColor="@color/textLightPrimary"  />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_item_options"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bt_order"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bt_rounded_corner"
                android:fontFamily="@font/microbrew_two"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="@string/btn_add_to_order"
                android:textColor="@color/backgroundLightSecondary"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: fix the button in center so it will not be pushed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In such cases, the best way is to use a `ConstraintLayout` as the container. As you mentioned in the question, you want to lay the `RecyclerView` at the center. So, it leads to binding its top and bottom to the buttons.

On the other hand, if we make a chain between the `RecyclerView` and `submitButton` with a vertical chain style of `packed`, the `submitButton` would stick to the bottom of `RecyclerView` (which height is `wrap_content` to be able to grow) and moves with its bottom until it reaches the bottom of the screen (because of `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`).

The key point is to set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` for the `RecyclerView` leading to not overlap with the two buttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/closeImageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/submitButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/closeImageButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Visual Result:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. I have a different use case that you may be able to help with. If I wanted a TextView above the recycler view that would pin itself to the top, so when the recycler view was smaller it would have the text view on top and the submit on bottom, how would I adjust this view for that? (new requirement I didn't have when I first asked this question)

Comment: Actually, nvm. Constraining the views to the top of the recycler and adding the chain style of packed works perfectly. This is great. I wasn't aware of how the chain style and constrained height worked. Will award you the rep once the timeframe has past. Can't do it for another 4 hours. Thanks you.

Comment: You're welcome dude:) I'm glad to see it was helpful to you.

Comment: @aminography it is possible to make the background of the button area transparent?

Comment: @mario: There is no problem with it. In the above example, the background is transparent and the white area is because of the activity background.

Comment: how can I get this to work if I'm adding the recycle view with a layout inflater dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand You want a button on top followed by recyclerview and than a Submit button in the end.And if size of recyclerview grows Submit button should not change its place.

Try this I make a rough layout

```
<LinearLayout  //This is root layout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output of code looks like this

[image]

Comment: This does not center the recycler view and submit button for smaller recycler content. it just causes the recycler content to fill the middle space regardless of its content size.

Comment: So you want Submit button always at the end of recyclerview? Or Submit button for smaller recyclerview at the end and for large recyclerview Submit button should at the bottom of screen like shown in image.

Comment: It should always be at the end of the recycler view, but the recycler view should not overflow the bounds of it's parent or push the button below the bounds of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything you want in just one hierarchy by using ConstraintLayout. As an example, I edited your XML code as below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_close"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_close"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_item_options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bt_order"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_close" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_order"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv_item_options" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: With this, if the recycler view's content grows too large, it does not scroll and the button still gets shoved off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: This also does not accomplish the goal. With this, the recycler view always fills the space between the top and bottom of the parent ConstraintLayout in between the two buttons. The recycler view and submit button do not, for smaller content sizes in the recycler, center themselves in the parent view.